# How to insert data in SQL temporary table from stored procedure in one query using PHP and drop table after getting resultset?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have to execute these queries in PHP to get the result

```
CREATE TABLE #tempDept(deptid int)

INSERT INTO #tempDept 
    EXEC sprinter_DeptHier1 22;

# This will create a temporary table and insert the result of stored procedure into the temp table

select * 
from sprinter_leave_request slr 
where slr.id not in (select lr.leave_request_id 
                     from leave_approver lr 
                     where lr.approver_id = 980)

// get userid from session and userid in (select userid from userinfo
where defaultdeptid in (select deptid from #tempDept)) and slr.userid
<> 980 order by userid;

# This query will get the result from temp table
```

And after getting the result I have to drop the table before next transition occurs.

Kindly help me out to solve the issue, I have to execute the query as same as in the question.

I tried so but have no luck.

Comment: Your queries hard to read in THAT formatting. Quotes are usually used for error messages, for queries use - code formatting.

Comment: If you run all this code via php, I suggest you create `#temptable` with unique for every run name like `#temptable` + current time in unix format and after all code simply run `DROP TABLE #temptable123`